# How do I get the numbers at the beginning of each line of a text file?

Tags: python, string, text, text-processing

I have a .txt file that has a number of lines in it, i.e.

```
230498soieung
3984sdgoij
032498eersn
```

How do I access this text file and then get a list of those numbers, i.e.

```
230498, 3984, 032498
```

If I can do this in Python, that is preferable.

Comment: show us your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re` module to manipulate text, you can use `\d+` to match multiple numbers and use `match()` to search from beginning.

```
import re
lines = ['230498soieung', '3984sdgoij', '032498eersn']
[re.match('\d+', line).group() for line in lines]
```

out:

```
['230498', '3984', '032498']
```

Comment: Maybe throw in a `^` so it only matches at the beginning of the line, just in case...

Comment: @kindall `match() == search('^')`

Comment: Oh, yeah, always get that confused.